# min3D framework load .OBJ and .3DS. Resume redraw

Tags: android, opengl-es, .obj, onresume

I've been using [min3D framework](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/) for my last project and I'm stack with couple of problems.

First - it takes a lot of effort to get it load my car model from `.OBJ` file.

I've managed to do it only by converting .obj file to `.3ds`(this was the only way to reduce size from `5mb` to `1mb` which I can put and read from the assets folder) but I still have some issues like missing edges(some parts of the car just doesn't draw).
Second - I'm having a hard time to reload my OpenGL on the Resume.

I need to redraw the model again after hitting 'back' button but I can do it only if I parse the `.3ds` file again. It takes too much memory and time to do it over and over again and if I try to use already parsed `ObjContainer` it just doesn't draw(I got blank OpenGL view).

So to summarize my questions are:

1. How to properly load huge(3-5mb) `.OBJ` or `.3DS` files via `min3D` framework and don't loose any parts of a model?
2. How to redraw a model again onResume without parsing `.OBJ` file over and over again?

Comment: I am not familiar with the min3D framework, but I would advise to parse the **obj** file with a tool and dump it into a binary format containing the list of vertices in OpenGL friendly array. If you are worrying about the size, use indices to avoid duplicate ones. At the start of the app do a load and keep it in memory and reupload to GPU `onResume`.